# Serializable parcelable issue: RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Tags: android, serialization, serializable, parcelable

Folks, I have simplest class which I want to be Parcelable. I'm doing it in following way:

```
public class MyField implements Serializable, Parcelable
{

    public MyField()
    {
    }


    //************************************************
    // Parcelable methods
    //************************************************
    public int describeContents() {return 0; };

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags)
    {
        out.writeInt(this.describeContents());
        out.writeSerializable(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("redundant")       
    public Parcelable.Creator<MyField> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<MyField>()
    {
        public MyField createFromParcel(Parcel in)
        {
            int description=in.readInt();
            Serializable s=in.readSerializable();
            switch(description)
            {
                case 0:
                    return (MyField )s;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public MyField[] newArray(int size)
        {
            return new MyField[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Simple, heh? Yes, looks like. But when I try to send my class object to another activity as parcel object like:

```
    intent=new Intent(activity, SendMessageActivity.class);
    MyField fld=new MyField();
    intent.putExtra("to", (Parcelable )fld);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

I'm getting following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = ru.ivanovpv.android.storage.MyField)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1131)
at ru.ivanovpv.android.storage.MyField.writeToParcel(MyField.java:58)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1106)
at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1029)
at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:469)
at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1445)
at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:483)
at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:5237)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1204)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1373)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2749)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2855)
at ru.ivanovpv.android.storage.BulkContact.doContextItemSelected(BulkContact.java:105)
at ru.ivanovpv.android.cellmessenger.ContactsActivity.onContextItemSelected(ContactsActivity.java:188)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2174)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2731)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:129)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ru.ivanovpv.android.storage.MyField$1
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:1153)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:420)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1251)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1587)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1854)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1696)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1660)
at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1126)
... 31 more
```

Can't really understand what's here is unserializable?

Answer (score 6):

Everything is pretty simple: "CREATOR" in the Parcelable implementation should be the "public static final" field - not just "public".

By leaving the "CREATOR" field just "public" you're making it a member of the MyField class. And as "CREATOR" is not "Serializable" - so you're getting a crash while system attempts to serialize all members of the MyField class.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you are mixing `Serializable` with `Parcelable`. No need to mix them both, `Parcelable` is Google's personal implementation of `Serializable`. Don't need to do it, it mixes thing up. For example, if you are creating a new `MyField()`, why are you casting in the next line of code. Try to clean up the code, focusing on "the Android way" to do it. Check the examples on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

Comment: Nope - incorrect. Error persist even if I cleans Parcelable implementation such that MyField implements only Serializable... that means - your suggestion is false

Comment: Well, then update the code and the error then because at this moment it still implements both of them and the error is at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1126), so if you are not implementing Parcelable it must show another error.